# Get geometric orientation of a flat desk

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection

I am attempting to get geometric orientation (Allocentric or egocentric) of a table using computer vision, such that my rover (on which the camera is placed), can align itself to its front face (the lower slant).

The table/panel looks similar to this [image]

What way should I go ?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some information with regard to the angles (20 degrees rotated to left, 30 degrees rotated to right/perpendicular), you would need to use a CNN network to classify between different positions of the desk (left/right/front).

Otherwise if you need additional metadata, you could train an image-depth model to extract the depth-per-pixel information, for your Egocentric task.

Comment: What if I have RGBD data ? Also, I would like to know the how is the object/table oriented with respect to the rover

Comment: Since the D stands for Depth, you could extract the depth-per-pixel information from the data; if all your photos are like that, you could slice the channel D and train for the orientation only on RGB information. In this way, you can use a dataset both for orientation prediction (rover vs table) and use the dataset(with depth information) to train a network to give you the per-pixel distance w.r.t to every object.